# Can we open a pdf or ppt document in a dialog in SharePoint online modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages

I have a SharePoint Modern Page with an image web part. The Image is linked to open the a pdf or ppt document. While clicking on the image it opens the file in the same window or tab.

Can we open the file in a popup like dialog or window?

Please help me on this.

Comment: Not using the SharePoint out of the box web parts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint out of the box web parts.

In SharePoint we have:

1. [Image web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-image-web-part-a63b335b-ad0a-4954-a65d-33c6af68beb2):

   - It shows the selected image in the web part
   - If `Link` is not provided in web part settings, it opens the image in pop up
   - If `Link` is provided: If the link is internal (from same site), it will open in same tab. If the link is from external web site, it will open in new tab
2. [File and Media (File viewer) web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-file-and-media-web-part-e53a9602-e7b3-4fff-9126-de2f18d1900c)

   - Shows the selected file directly inside the site page
   - No dialog/pop up functionality with this web part.

So, you will have to create a custom SPFx web part for your requirements. Check below links for more information:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)
2. [Build your first SharePoint SPFx client-side web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)
3. [SPFx web part samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples) - check if there is any relevant sample web part available on this GitHub repository which you can refer for your web part development